# is there any way to automate one table data insertion depending on another table data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

don't know if it's possible or not, but I'm wondering if I can automate the insertion of MySQL **table2** depending on **table1**

Let's say I've two tables ( **table1** and **table2** ) in my database. and what I want is an automation, which will automatically create a new row in **table2** with some default values whenever a new row is created in **table1**. so that I don't have to write insertion code for **table2** in my PHP file

Don't know if I've made it enough clear. let me brief my table structure in a nutshell...

**table1** :-

- user_name ( *unique* )
- user_email

**table2** :-

- user_name ( *same as **table1*** )
- is_account_active ( *true as default* )
- invested ( *0 as default* )
- current_balance( *0 as default* )

so whenever an account is created, I'm inserting new data both in **table1** and **table2**. so I'm wondering if I can create the **table2** in a specific way that whenever a new row is created in **table1**, **table2** will automatically pull user_name from **table1**'s new row and insert it in its own storage ( the rest of the column data are static. so I can set defaults for 'em )

[ NOTE: I need to keep 'em in two different tables as there'll be many columns in each table ]

<-- I know many of you'll ask for what I tried. but tbh I don't even have any idea what to try -->

Comment: Start with DB Triggers https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [AFTER INSERT TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_table1_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_name  IS NOT NULL AND NEW.user_email  IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO table2 (user_name,is_account_active, invested, current_balance)
        VALUES(NEW.user_name,1,0,0);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You need to add all columns that you want to use in table2 with NEW.column_name